# Can I use docker compose to run application container and its dependencies on google cloud or digital ocean, the same as locally?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-platform

I have a spring boot application, angular front end app, couchbase, and redis. They are all defined in a docker compose yaml file. I can make the application up and running locally. Is there a way to use docker compose tools/commands to do the same in google cloud or digital ocean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want/need platform-specific integrations and transforming your services to a cloud I guess [GCP Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) is for you -- it's like a usual virtual machine that you can start, SSH to it and have all privileges to install and run software the same way you did it on your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid Kubernetes, then the simplest of the [GCP options for a docker container](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers) is probably their Container-optimized VM images?

That lets you put the parameters to your `docker run ...` command in the VM config as per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#gcloud

This assumes you are able to publish your image to a repo that is accessible to your GCP compute VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Google Cloud but **yes on Digital Ocean**, I do it all the time! Just make sure you have [Docker Compose installed](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install) on the droplet and then run the commands the same as you do locally.

Comment: Why was this downvoted.  I'm asking as it fits my use case perfectly so keen to understand why it's not considered a good answer.

Comment: @Auspice I would like to know that myself! I think it's a perfectly valid answer, it could have just been someone being spiteful. I recently started a new job and my new company also uses docker-compose on their servers, although it's not Digital Ocean.

Comment: Thanks Jacob (sorry couldn't insert your @name.  Actually since I posted my comment I have made progress doing exactly this.  In fact on Digital Ocean there is a specific Droplet Template which comes with Docker ready installed which made it very easy, so not only is this a valid answer, but it's the one I used.

Comment: That's great @Auspice glad I was able to help! I've also updated my name so it should be taggable now, thanks for letting me know!